# Design for 2 closely related (1 for 1) classes that may alter each other

Tags: c#, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I have a program that communicates with an API to get information on different organizations, so I have an `Organization` class and an `ApiCall` class which are both closely related. As the API I'm using requires different tokens, url endpoints and authentifications to be used depending on the organization I'm trying to get data, I use a different instance of `ApiCall` for each instance of `Organization` (basically a 1-1 relationship).

So the first thing that comes to mind is to have an `ApiCall` instance as a property of `Organization`, however the api class has several methods that can alter or update data from the `Organization` class.

So there are many ways of implementing this. Personally I was considering 4 of them:

1. A circular reference, where Organization holds an ApiCall instance as a property and `ApiCall` holds an `Organization` instance
2. I could have ApiCall as a nested class inside `Organization`, however both classes are fairly sizeable (>300 lines) so I don't like the idea of mixing them. So maybe have `Organization` as a partial class where one file has the `Organization` methods implementation and the other file has the nested class (`ApiCall`) implementation?
3. Have a static `Dictionary` shared across the program correlating the `Organization` and `ApiCall` instances
4. Split `Organization` in 2 classes, `OrgData` and `OrgActions`, where `OrgActions` references `ApiCall` and `OrgData` and `ApiCall` references `OrgData`

I'm leaning towards alternatives 2 or 4 at the moment, but I was wondering what others would consider the better choice.

Comment: ApiCall sounds like an operation (a verb) and Organization sounds like a noun, so I would keep them separate, or make Organization a parameter or property of ApiCall, and remove references to ApiCall from Organization.

Comment: Is an Organization going to reuse its same Apicall? Or can the organization use these as one-time-use objects, i.e. `new ApiCall(this).DoSomeWork()`? Or does the ApiCall actually retain state/data for a functional purpose?

Answer (score 1):

First get your responsabilities and names right. It looks to me this is what you have:

**OrganizationInfo**

This is just a data class, it knows nothing about any API or connection parameters.

**ConnectionInfo**

This holds parameters to establish the connection with the data source. It knows nothing about an API or organizations.

**Connector**

This has behavior. It knows how to connect to the data sources, using a ConnectionInfo object. It can on request deliver an OrganizationInfo object for a particular specified organization.

**Fetcher**

This knows the first three classes and retrieves all organization info records.

You have no circular references.

Comment: If you cut ConnectionInfo then that's essentially what I suggested in alternative 4: to split Organization into OrgData and OrgActions(that you call Fetcher). Any specific reason why you think ConnectionInfo is necessary? I don't see why things like security tokens, token expiration times or other similar data shouldn't be fields of the class making the requests to the API.

Comment: @Lucas The class making the call is only interested in the org. info, it should not know about (have dependencies towards) technical details of the connection. Separation of concerns.

Comment: That's like saying Person object should have a single field PersonData, and a PersonData class with info like name, age, and so on. If we go by that logic then all the classes on every program would be split into data classes and method classes that hold data classes as properties, which seems like completely overdoing it. Both Connector and Connectioninfo have the same concern, which is the connection, and it's almost certain that ConnectionInfo only interacts with the Connector without ever getting accessed by any other class of the program, so I still disagree these two should be separate.

Comment: @Lucas A person does not have a different name every time it is interacted with. Your person data is very much hard-tied to a particular individual. A connector however connects to different sources depending on the connection info it gets passed. There is but one connector, it could even be static. It is the connection info that varies.

Comment: @Lucas Separating data structures from behavior is perfectly valid and natural if you do it in the application from the start, rather than having some classes with behavior and some without. If you do not need stateful objects, then data structures + functions is often a simpler way of coding than normal OOP where data/behavior get blended.

Answer (score -2):

Your ApiCall should accept an Interface as a parameter.

In other words, you should have an ApiCall method that takes an IOrganization interface with different implementations

```
public interface IOrganization
{
    void CallOutToServer();
}

public class OrgType1 : IOrganization
{
    public void CallOutToServer()
    {
        // implement the callout logic here
    }
}

public class OrgType2 : IOrganization
{
    public void CallOutToServer()
    {
        // implement the callout logic here
    }
}

public class APiCall
{
    public void DoCallOut(IOrganization org)
    {
        org.CallOutToServer();
    }
}
```